# How do I pass down components spread props with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

EDIT: I focused too much on TypeScript that I didn't realize I wasn't mapping the data. It works now.

I am just starting to use TypeScript, and I can't figure out how to pass down props with the spread operator. How should I do this? from what I understand I shouldn't be using React.FC so I am trying to do it with interface, but still don't understand how to get the props. Thank you

Index.tsx:

```
    const Home: NextPage = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        console.log(data)
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((json) => setData(json));
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <CustomComponent {...data} />
            </div>
        );
    };

export default Home;
```

CustomComponent.tsx:

```
    interface Props {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

const CustomComponent = ({ userId }: Props) => {
    console.log(userId);
    return <div>{userId}</div>;
};

export default CustomComponent;
```

Comment: *"...from what I understand I shouldn't be using React.FC..."* Why not?

Comment: <pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what spread and rest syntax do.</pedantry>

Comment: You're trying to use spread on an array in a place where only *property* spread is supported. Why are you trying to use spread at all? It looks like `CustomComponent` only takes a single prop. You'd use spread if `data` contained multiple properties that matched the names of the props that `CustomComponent` expects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Why is React.FC discouraged](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components/)

Comment: Just FWIW, I wouldn't say there's a general consensus around that particular opinion, but I wouldn't necessarily *know*, either, so don't read too much into that. It's not relevant to what you're asking about in any case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am just experimenting right now, not trying to do anything in particular. Might have chosen a bad example to post, but I am eventually just trying to understand how to do it when I actually need it.

Comment: Well, the only problem with what you're doing is specifically what you're doing in the post, so... If `data` were an object with a `userId` property (instead of an array), what you have would be fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was too focused on typescript that I didn't realize I'm not mapping the data lol so I guess that makes sense. Thank you for your help

Comment: No worries! I've posted an answer doing what I think you meant to do (the more I looked at it, the more clear it became). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use spread on an array (`data`) in a place where only *property* spread is supported (the props list of a JSX element expression). Although arrays are objects, their property names are `"0"` and such, not `"userId"` and such, so that doesn't match the props expected by the component.

You've said in a comment that you aren't trying to do anything in particular, just trying to see how to do what you're doing. Your `<CustomComponent {...data}>` is just fine **if** `data` is an object, but it's an array.

It looks like your data source returns this:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    ...
]
```

If so, you probably want an array of `CustomComponent`, and then use `...` to spread out *each element* of `data` into the props of each `CustomComponent`.

To do that, you have to set the type of `data` correctly. Define an interface/object type:

```
interface PostInfo {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
```

then use an array of those in the `setState` type arggument so TypeScript knows what's in the array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<PostInfo[]>([]);
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then render an *array* of components:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        {data.map(post => <CustomComponent key={post.id} {...post} />)}
    </div>
);
```

Here's a live example with the TypeScript parts commented out:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const styles = {
    container: "container",
};

/*
interface PostInfo {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
*/
const Home/*: NextPage*/ = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState/*<PostInfo[]>*/([]);
    console.log(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => setData(data/* as PostInfo[]*/));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {data.map(post => <CustomComponent key={post.id} {...post} />)}
        </div>
    );
};

/*
interface Props {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
*/

const CustomComponent = ({ userId, id, title }/*: Props*/) => {
    return <div>userId: {userId}, id: {id}, title: {title}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

And the full TypeScript ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYltCkBRAMzqQwF846oIQ4AiKVDbgG4AUMID0YuAApSKAHYATALTA5ASmFoIcgvF0BPADZICcALy5hca3C1yyqpFABcPOw7lPumYcxHDVCig6dCQ4AAUIXQBJOToISxs4aihohVc5PBAAIycRJOB0uEycvKsbGGAYY1ddKFUAcxFmTW1dOAAJTiQxACpXADkkAA8YcJQGpF7JCyk1cwA+RJs7doBtBXIUbCIYABEtgF1zZKJZCgAeSJi4iDXDhal7tXybCSSPz6-vgD0--4Bf3K1lWEGMADpDBAGlJNmQNMDTrQGEwYFI5otlp9GDA0AALKQAcjxMBgYAIzgkACsCNowIZQniwQonOCYPowMAtCzwVoQGJILoCGJCRpvkk2XikHJ0XwCJAdEh5mYljhEeKbMA6NIAIRyhVEcEQADW8zVGo1MDxHAA7sUkHaaFAOFApAADDoAFU94TgThdcAAJDh9W0kODdORCMw3S91RaWhaPnwYHgoHI4KHFeCado5q8NcwxRbJdL0XCUMqlrsDmRYVs4ChTNcYLF4s840lmNhnv4kim0xmpPHrBcFMAAG62BkEAgDFAgJBmHAGYwEXnaDxOZgLEcfHAV8EgFBgKSC+AquAXADChBgnGvnAV0vgOHB7-PrDECzUia+FzEccJ13JI4z8URAicEI0DCcIOHJLEkVSIoSlyKACzgQoMiyNCMMqaokFqGB6jkJpfFEVZ4FvXQHyfbQXxOKQcCQtJsEKbB8OMOBmFcOCIHJKtEIHdMryAhYUjSVx8CIZDu0woocEKOTOMI3AVOYACxOaEQgA)):

```typescript
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

// (Stand-in)
const styles = {
    container: "container",
};

interface PostInfo {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
const Home/*: NextPage*/ = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<PostInfo[]>([]);
    //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => setData(data as PostInfo[]));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {data.map(post => <CustomComponent {...post} />)}
        </div>
    );
};

interface Props {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

const CustomComponent = ({ userId, id, title }: Props) => {
    return <div>userId: {userId}, id: {id}, title: {title}</div>;
};
```